# How to autowire a class from a maven dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I currently have a dependency project added in from pom.xml and that has all the config and everything included already. Is it possible to autowire a class from a jar dependency maven?

Comment: WHy wouldn't it. It is part of the classpath and everything is available. It is no different than doing the same for your own classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I did try with Autowire but I get Could not autowire. No beans of type ".." found. I have SpringBootApplication in my main class. I can import the class but not autowire them

Comment: Is it already a Spring Bean? If so, auto wiring shouldn't be a problem. If it's not a spring bean then you must declare a bean of its type.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero the config and set up is in the dependency jar. I am hoping to just Autowire it without repeating the config from the dependency maven project. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: There's a lot of a grey area in your question. Is this dependency an auto-configure application? If so, it should work. If it's not an auto-configure, you need to make sure the classes/packages are scanned and loaded to the application context, which I personally do not recommend. You can also declare the beans you need or make a @Import to the configuration class with the beans declarations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use scanBasePackage in your application.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.myrootpackage"})
```

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Scanning a third-party library can bring many side effects and even conflicts with your own application context. You better use an auto-configure library or import the configuration classes you need, or (the safest in my experience) declare the necessary beans within the target application.